# Origin of the "breach" sense of "compromise"

Tags: etymology, homographs

Both [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compromise) and [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=compromise) give the origin of compromise as Latin *com* (together) +  *promittere* (promise).  This is the most common use of this word: to mutually promise to [abide by an arbitrated decision.]

However, the word also has the sense of impairing or breaching, as in "to compromise one's reputation [due to one's inappropriate action]" or "to compromise national security [by revealing information]."  Where did this meaning of compromise originate?

Comment: Does it have to be an arbitrated decision?  I'd say what you call the common meaning is to agree to abide by a mutual decision in which the parties each make concessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "compromise" developed from a Latin verb with a cognate in (almost?) all Romance languages (French *'compromettre'*, Spanish *'comprometer'*, Portuguese *'comprometer'*, Italian *'compromettere'*, Romanian *'compromis'*), it may be useful to look it up in etimological dictionaries in other languages. In this case, I found an Italian etimological dictionary ([etimo.it](http://www.etimo.it/?term=compromettere&find=Cerca)) that relates 'compromettere' as "agree" and as "put in danger". Here's a rough translation:

> Compromèttere: from Latin COM-PROMITTERE. To put in arbitration some decision, each part agreeing to obbey whatever is to be decided. Since this way to put an end to controversies could expose oneself to danger because of a decision that could turn out to be unfair but unappealable, the word Compromettere ended up being used to say "to put (something or someone) in danger with actions not meditated upon".

The shift in meaning from "arbitrate" to "expose to danger" is present in most Romance languages (I can tell it is in Spanish, Italian and Portuguese). [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compromise) defines "compromise" as:

> - to expose (something) to risk or danger
> - to damage or weaken (something)

I cannot assert the process of shifting from one meaning to another in English was the same as it was in Italian, but it could be useful as an insight. The thing is, such process is registered in at least one language, so maybe it's a good thing to start with.

Answer (score 3):

It came from a sense it developed in English that it doesn't have in Latin.  In English, this coming together to reach a promise or agreement became synonymous with the part of the process in which one concedes some of what they initially set out to get.  Compromise then became married to the idea of concession, of giving up ground, of somewhat losing in original position.

When someone is compromised in the sense that you describe, it means that they have lost ground, they've been breached, they've lost their position, and so they are no longer viable.  They in essence become like a compromise lost at the negotiation table: off the table.

Answer (score 2):

According to [A New English Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=Qk9gAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA2-PR479&dq=compromise&hl=en&sa=X&v=onepage&f=false) (published in 1739), there were at that time only two definitions of the word.

> [*n.*] [A] mutual Promise of Parties to refer a Business to Arbitration.
>   [*v.*] [To] consent to such a Reference.

So, the "*breach*" meaning is not recorded at that time in this dictionary. However, we see it used in this way (or in a way that can be construed as such) in [The Historical Register, Containing An Impartial Relation of all Transactions, *Foreign* and *Domestick*.](https://books.google.com/books?id=j9sRAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), a record of the proceedings in London, in the *Old Baily*, for the year 1725.

On [page 67](https://books.google.com/books?id=j9sRAAAAYAAJ&v=onepage&q&f=false&pg=PA67#v=onepage&q&f=false), we find the following entry.

> A Complaint being made to the House, That there had been some undue Practices in relation to the compromising the Election for the Borough of *Stafford* in the County of *Stafford*, before the Merits of the said Election were heard before the Committee of Privileges and Elections; it was thereupon Ordered, That the Report from the Committee of Privileges and Elections touching the Election for the said Borough of *Stafford* (which was ordered to be received this Day) be received upon Thursday Seven-night, the 4th of *February*, when several Persons were order'd to attend.

The followup to this proceeds on [page 73](https://books.google.com/books?id=j9sRAAAAYAAJ&v=onepage&q&f=false&pg=PA73#v=onepage&q&f=false).

> The next Day, (*Feb. 4.*) the House proceeded (according to Order) to take into Consideration the Matter of the Complaint, [made to the House the 23rd Day of *January* last] That there had been some undue Practices in relation to the compromising the Election for the Borough of *Stafford*, before the Merits of the said Election were heard before the Committee of Privileges and Elections. And several Witnesses were called in and examined at the Bar, touching the Matter of the said Complaint. And then they withdrew. And it was *Resolved*, That it appears to this House, that divers indirect and corrupt Practices have been used in order to compromise the Election for the Borough of *Stafford*, before the fame was heard before the Committee of Privileges and Elections.
>   *Resolved, Nemine Contradicente*, That it appears to this House, that *Francis Elde*, Esq; (A Member of this House) has been guilty of the said indirect and corrupt Practices, highly reflecting upon the Honour and Justice of Parliament.
>   *Resolved, Nemine Contradicente*, that the said *Francis Elde*, Esq; (a Member of this House) be, for his said Offence, expelled this House.
>   A Motion being made, and the Question being put, That it appears to this House, that *Walter* Lord Viscount *Chetwynd* in the Kingdom of *Ireland*, who petitioned this House, complaining of an undue Election and Return for the Borough of *Stafford*, has been guilty of indirect and corrupt Practices in order to compromise the Election for the said Borough, before the fame was heard before the Committee of Privileges and Elections: It passed in the Negative.

(NB: The Latin phrase, *nemine contradicente*, translates to "no one spoke against it". In today's parlance, we would say "unanimously" or "without dissent".)

Reading on, you see that Francis Elde attempted to usurp the role of Burgess of the Borough of Stafford after the death of John Dolphin from the duly elected Walter Lord Viscount Chetwynd. Corroborating this with the [Journals of the House of Lords for 1724](https://books.google.com/books?id=FhtDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA462&lpg=PA462&dq=francis+elde&source=bl&ots=yJ8FKrCNeq&sig=HVm5syLBoC01jqiXU7J8CEB4Huc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjMytDCn5jKAhXHQiYKHR_gDx4Q6AEIOTAG#v=onepage&q=francis%20elde&f=false), Francis Elde had a history of such activity, having bribed the Lord Chancellor the preceding year so he could become a Master of the Court of Chancery.

We can see in these entries how the "*mutual agreement*" meaning starts to drift to "*breach*". By not mentioning the other party as a direct object, though, precedent was set to define this word as an action that breaches the rights or honors of another. Francis Elde made a mutual agreement with the Committee of Privileges and Elections (perhaps without the committee's knowledge of the deceit) to breach the rights of Walter Lord Viscount Chetwynd, who was not party to this agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a [back formation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/back-formation) from ***uncompromising*** which means: (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/uncompromising)

> 1. not admitting of compromise or adjustment of differences; making no concessions; inaccessible to flexible bargaining; unyielding: an
>      uncompromising attitude.
>
>    2. without reservation or exception; undeviating; absolute, as believing in or adhering to a principle, position, or the like: an
>         uncompromising abolitionist.

So, ***un- un-compromising,***  (that is ***compromising:)***

> making concessions...deviating ....**not** believing in  or adhering to principle.

[Compromise is not defined in Samuel Johnson.]